# Python importing list of lists as string

Tags: python

I'm importing a text file containing a list of lists and trying to sum each row, but I'm getting the error 'unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str''.

However, if I cut and paste the contents into the code, everything works.

test_list.txt is [[3, 5, 7, 11, 13], [3, 5, 7, 11, 17], [3, 5, 7, 11, 19]].

Trying to run the following code:

```
with open('test_list.txt', 'r',) as f:
    data = f.read()
    row_sums = [sum(row) for row in data]
    print (row_sums)

[39, 43, 45]
```

Comment: Is the data file actually like this (everything on one line), or are you missing new lines in the question?

Comment: You have json data, so you need to import json module and `data = json.loads(f.read())`

Comment: The data file is all on one line.

Comment: *However, if I cut and paste the contents into the code, everything works.* Right, but if you paste them **as a string** (`data = "[[3, 5, 7, 11, 13], [3, 5, 7, 11, 17], [3, 5, 7, 11, 19]]"`) then you'll see the same problem that you get when reading  from the file.

Comment: Importing json solved problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`type(data)` is `<class 'str'>` and you are treating it as nested list.

```
import json
with open('test_list.txt', 'r',) as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read()) 
    row_sums = [sum(row) for row in data]
    print(row_sums)
```

Answer (score -1):

`f.read()` returns the content of the file `f` as a *string*, so in the generator expression `row_sums = [sum(row) for row in data]` you are iterating over the characters...

Instead, parse the string as a list (e.g. by `ast.literal_eval(data)`, see [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval))

Comment: Invoking a full scale Python parser for this particular use case appears rather excessive; parsing the text as JSON, as suggested in other responses, seems entirely sufficient